# Should Programmers Upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10

Tags: windows, performance, upgrade

I am a VisualC# programmer and an individual Unity3d game developer. I wanted to know if there was any problem if I upgraded from my windows 7 to windows 10, I wanted to know if there is any difference in performance. And one more thing.. From a programmers point of view is there any feature that I would not be able to get if I do not activate windows,meaning that I use deactivated Windows because I donot think why should I activate it.

Comment: _I use deactivated Windows because I don't think I should activate it_ well, if all your games, programs and apps are free and will always be free you're good, otherwise you need to activate Windows in order to legally sell them.

Answer (score 0):

New Windows versions introduce new API. E.g. [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx) was only added in Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I needed to ask as a technical advice if my system will slow down on installing win10 .

Comment: My System : Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU   M540 @ 2.53GHz 2.53GHz           RAM : 4GB          System Type : 32-bit